# deactivate an item in the file button "jewel" in crm 2011

Tags: customization, dynamics-crm-2011

is it possible to hide or deactivate a menu item in the file button called also jewel button? I´m able to hide completely the file button with javascript, but I want to hide or disable only some menu items in the flyout menu.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

You will find these Jewel buttons within the application ribbon. You can choose to hide these buttons in your customizations.xml via some hide HideCustomActions. The names of some of the Jewel buttons you will find are:

```
 - Mscrm.Jewel.NewMenu.NewActivity
 - Mscrm.Jewel.NewMenu.NewRecord;
```

For example, within your appointment ribbondiffxml section within your customizations.xml, you could have a `HideCustomAction` like:

```
<HideCustomAction HideActionId="CustomHideAction.JewelMenu.NewActivity" Location="Mscrm.Jewel.NewMenu.NewActivity" />
```

Comment: Here is how to use the HideCustomAction XML step-by-step: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crmdevelopment/thread/19dd9b1c-68d6-4e3d-bcce-23646bde2bbf#b32170ab-45b6-4058-bf91-dc2dde98dac9